# How do you apply "-zapwallettxes" on Windows?

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, windows

On May 27 I tried to sell some Bitcoins(for the first time). Since that day the transaction is in the status "unconfirmed". The amount is booked from my wallet, but isn't booked to my bank account.

The solution I found to solve my problem was to start the Bitcoin core wallet with "`-zapwallettxes`". I'm using Win10 and don't find a way to do this.

Has anyone got any idea on what can I do to sell or to get back the Bitcoin? Answers in German are welcome too.

Comment: where did you sell the Bitcoins ? You can contact that Bitcoin exchange with the matter.

Answer (score 8):

`-zapwallettxes` removes all wallet transactions that are not in the blockchain. It can remove "stuck" transactions, although you don't need this feature in normal operations mode.

**Solution A)**

On Windows, you need to start the command line prompt (cmd.exe), go to your window search and enter "cmd" and start `cmd.exe`.
Start bitcoin-qt with `--zapwallettxes=1`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe --zapwallettxes=1
```

(maybe adapt the program files path)

**Solution B)**

Create a `bitcoin.conf` file (normal textfile) here:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin (XP)
C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin (Vista and 7)
```

Place....

```
zapwallettxes=1
```

... in the `bitcoin.conf` file, start Bitcoin-Qt, remove the `zapwallettxes=1`, restart Bitcoin-Qt.

Comment: Solution B (creating a configuration file) worked fine. Thanks a lot Jonas!

Comment: This solution worked initially,  but after a day,  the unconfirmed transaction reappeared in the wallet.  My suspicion is that it came back because it is already in the mempool and is being rebroadcast back to the client...

Comment: The solution that worked for me was using a transaction accelerator service.  For $4, I got the transaction unstuck

Comment: how is this not documented at all?