# How to run --zapwalletxes command?

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows

I am having problems running the `--zapwalletxes` command from the cmd prompt.  I type `C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitcoin\bitcoin-qt.exe --zapwalletxes=1`.  After entering this the CMD prompt states that C:\Program Files is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  If anyone could help troubleshoot that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: related: [How do you apply “-zapwallettxes” on Windows?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/45988/5406)

Answer (score 1):

```
--zapwalletxes
```

You're missing a 't'. It's `-zapwallettxes`.

Also, you may need to adapt the path to the actual installation directory of the program on your computer.