# How do you apply “-zapwallettxes” for multbit 0.5.15

Tags: transactions, wallet, wallet-recovery

I made a transaction a few months ago but the transaction is still not confirmed, the Bitcoins are debited from my account and the balance in my wallet is zero.

Information on the transaction

```
The transaction is seen by 1 peer and the status of this transaction is still unconfirmed.
```

I guess it is a bit of the same issue as described in this question: [How do you apply "-zapwallettxes" on Windows?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/45988/how-do-you-apply-zapwallettxes-on-windows)

Though I use the wallet MultiBit 0.5.15, the commands like -zapwallettxes does not work in my case.

Does anyone know how to restore this transaction, or what commands I should enter in cmd to fix this?