# Bitcoin core - creating transaction from UI without broadcasting it

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, wallet, raw-transaction

I would like to use Bitcoin core's wallet UI to create a transaction but instead of broadcasting it I would like to get the underlying raw transaction.

Is there a way to do that?

I assume that network sniffing tools might be able to help but I wonder if there is a direct way. I think it would be really useful to have such feature - view raw transaction & confirm before broadcast.

The motivation for this specific scenario is the following  - I would like to create a raw transaction on an offline machine running Bitcoin core (with synced blockhain) and broadcast the transaction from another machine.

I am aware that what I am asking for is easily achievable with the CLI but I'd like to use the convenience of a GUI (& fee calculations) and also avoid creating non-intended transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First you can add `connect=1.1.1.1` to your `bitcoin.conf`. Your node won't search for other nodes and just try to connect to 1.1.1.1. Since 1.1.1.1 is not a node, your node will have 0 peers.

2) Then you can make the transaction, open the debug console and enter: `gettransaction YOURTXID`. (or `getrawtransaction` to get the hex encoded transaction)

3) Then you can close Core, add [`zapwallettxes=1`](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/45988) to `bitcoin.conf` and start Core to remove unconfirmed wallet transaction you've made to cancel it.

Comment: Thank you. Took me a long time to test it but I can now confirm it works as intended.