# sendrawtransaction on a non-synced node

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, sendrawtransaction

This question is related to [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/bitcoin-core-creating-transaction-from-ui-without-broadcasting-it) post explaining how to use bitcoin-qt to generate a transaction.

Once obtained, I'd like to dispatch it from my system which is running a non-synced node. When issuing sendrawtransaction the following happens:

```
./bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction
error code: -26
error message:
non-final
```

I have two questions related to this

1. Am I right that this is caused by the fact that my node is not synced?
2. Is there a way to dispatch the transaction to the BTC  network anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right that this is caused by the fact that my node is not synced?

It certainly could be. The transaction could have a locktime that is in the past in reality, but is in the future from the perspective of the unsynced node.

> Is there a way to dispatch the transaction to the BTC network anyway?

Use a node that is synchronized. It doesn't need to be your own; you won't have RPC access to other nodes, but you can use a tool like bitcoin-submittx, or websites like block explorers that permit submitting transactions (possibly though Tor).